# How does this SQL code select the 2 most cheapest fruits?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this SQL code that I got from [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/). I am unable to understand how it works.

```
SELECT type, variety, price
FROM fruits
WHERE ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM fruits AS f
        WHERE f.type = fruits.type AND f.price <= fruits.price
      ) <= 2
```

The table can be found in the link mentioned above or you can click [here](https://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/), the code can be found in that link also

Comment: (a) not very efficiently, (b) by only selecting fruits that have 2 or fewer fruits (including themselves) that have the same or **lower** price (Typo?)

Comment: yes I misunderstood it, I'll make the corrections in the question right away!

Answer (score 1):

First, it doesn't.  To get the most expensive, the subquery would need `f.price >= fruits.price`.  It is getting the cheapest.  But let me assume that what you intend.

The logic it implements is really quite complicated.  But here are some scenarios:

- If the two most expensive fruits for a given type have unique prices, then it does what you want.
- If exactly two fruits tie for most expensive, then they are returned.
- If the 3 or more fruits tie for being most expensive for a given type, then it returns nothing.

There are much better ways to express this logic, using `dense_rank()` or `row_number()`, depending on the actual intention.

How does the query work?  The subquery is a *correlated subquery*.  The way to *think* about it is that for each row in the outer query, the inner query is run.  The inner query is counting the number of fruits of the same type subject to the condition on price -- the number with the same or higher price.  Note that the SQL engine may use a different execution plan.

The assumption is that if the subquery returns `1`, then the row is the highest price.  However, that assumption depends on the underlying data.

As I say, this is really a horrible way to accomplish this logic.  Learn window functions.  And use different examples to learn about correlated subqueries.